# Allow DISPLAY access for a user not logged on GUI

Tags: 14.04, ssh, 15.04, display

A user "usera" is logged on GUI on ubuntu 14.04.3 (same issue appears on 15.04).

When a user "userb" log on the PC through ssh, he can't launch a graphical application with `export DISPLAY=:0`, for example `nautilus` command return this error :

```
    No protocol specified

    ** (nautilus:30658): WARNING **: Could not open X display
    No protocol specified

    (nautilus:30658): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

This used to work in Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Is there a group or a setup to do to allow third-party users to launch graphical apps on screen ?

This is `w` command output :

```
userb@ubuntu:~$ w
11:57:05 up 0 min,  2 users,  load average: 0,11, 0,03, 0,01
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
usera    :0       :0               11:56   ?xdm?  13.44s  0.10s init --user
userb    pts/3    192.168.0.45     11:57    2.00s  0.03s  0.00s w
```

The problem isn't ssh, I can reproduce the same error when I launch a terminal on usera GUI, then typing `sudo userb` and `nautilus`.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Try with command `ssh username@server -X`

Comment: I do not want to open the app on the remote PC, but on the monitor plugged on the PC.

Comment: When you `ssh` to server with `-X` and type `nautilus`. `nautilus` will be exported via network to pc from witch you make ssh connection. If you have linux on `pc`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I want to open the app on the remote PC (ssh server), and not on client side, I do not want to do X11 forwarding.

Comment: What is the output of `w` on machine A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow all local (ie logged in) users to use the display by giving the command in a terminal on the graphics screen:

```
xhost +local:
```

Depending how you start your server you can put this command in a startup file, or even configure the server with the option.

Comment: thanks, the previous configuration `xhost +si:localuser:usera:` do not work on current Xorg version of ubuntu (1:7.7+1).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a program on a remote display from your computer you have to allow the remote connections. Usually you have to make a file /etc/X0.hosts for display 0, /etc/X1.hosts for display 1, etc. Maybe you need to do it also in your case. Try also writing the whole hostname when exporting display

```
export DISPLAY=hostname:0
```

Or make all in one line

```
DISPLAY=hostname:0.0 nautilus
```